# Can I delete an on-premises gateway in Azure?

Tags: azure, gateway, azure-logic-apps

Can't find any information on this anywhere - I saved incorrect settings on this one on creation and can't change them now. I want to create a new gateway in Azure to associate with the on-premises gateway installation I created on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can delete an on-premise data gateway in Azure (this effectively just removes the association between you on-premise data gateway installation and the Azure resource, it does not uninstall the on-premise data gateway itself).

In order to delete the gateway you would need to use a REST client (such as Postman) or Azure Powershell. The Azure portal does not currently support management of on-premise data gateway resources.

The gateway resource URI is

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subId}/resourceGroups/{rgName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/{gatewayName}?api-version=2016-06-01`

You need to use your azure bearer token for authentication.

Comment: whats wrong with powershell or cli? or that's not a vpn gateway, i'm not sure

Comment: Sorry, just getting around to testing this out... can you tell me where I can find my subId, and authentication token? I have only been using the UI up until this point.

Comment: Navigate to the resource group under which you created your data gateway resource (in Azure Portal) and you should see the subscription id under 'Essentials'. To get the token you can enable network tracing (either using a tool like Fiddler, or just open dev tools in your browser and turn network tracing on), and inspect any calls against management.azure.com (you want to copy the Authorization header value)

Comment: Great, it worked! For the record I wasn't able to find the authorization header in fiddler for some reason, but it did show up in devtools for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

April 2017

- **Portal UI**: Not possible
- **Azure CLI v1**: Says it's deleted... But it's not.

  azure resource delete resourceName Mygateway resourceType "Microsoft.Web/connectionGateway"
- **Azure PowerShell**: It works with the command

  Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup11/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/ContosoSite" -Force

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now that the [on-premises data gateway became generally available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premises-data-gateway-functionality-goes-ga-in-azure/) in early May 2017, you can delete your gateway resource from the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com). However, this capability applies only to the gateway resource, not the gateway installation.

From the main Azure menu, go to **All Resources**. Select your gateway resource. Go to **On-premises Data Gateway**, and on the toolbar, choose **Delete**. For example:

[image: Delete on-premises data gateway resource in Azure portal]

For more details, see:

[Access data on premises from Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection)

[Install the on-premises data gateway for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install)